# Jquery plugin access var from method using prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, prototype

I have the following javascript code using http://fr.jqueryboilerplate.com/

```
;(function ($, window, document, undefined) {
  var pluginName = "PluginName",
    defaults = {
      overlay: {
        BgColor: "#000",
        opacity: "0.6"
      }
    };
  function Plugin(element, options) {
    this.element = $(element);
    this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);
    this._defaults = defaults;
    this._name = pluginName;
    this.init();
  }
  Plugin.prototype = {
    init: function () {
      console.log("init");
      var overlay = jQuery("<div/>", {
        id: "ModalOverlay",
        click: function () {
          Plugin.prototype.Mymethod();
        }
      });
    },
    Mymethod: function () {}
  };
```

Anyone could teach me how can access to variables, whose are into

```
function Plugin(){}
```

from

```
Mymethod: function() {}
```

maybe something like that :

add store object

```
Plugin.prototype = {
  store: {
    _overlay: null
  }
```

Into init function

```
Plugin.prototype.store._overlay = overlay;
```

And then access it like :

```
Mymethod: function () {
  console.log(Plugin.prototype.store._overlay);
},
```

I'm pretty sure that's work, but i think that's very dirty.

Comment: have you tried to access it with `this.options.overlay` inside `Mymethod`?

Comment: Yeah, console said `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'overlay' of undefined `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, I have not tested it. but worth try . If does not work let me know and i will delete.

```
Plugin.prototype = {
init: function () {
  var myThis=this;
  console.log("init");
  var overlay = jQuery("<div/>", {
    id: "ModalOverlay",
    click: function () {
      myThis.Mymethod();
    }
  });
},
Mymethod: function () {
     alert(this._name);     
     alert(this.options);
     alert(this.options.overlay);
     console.log(this.options.overlay);

}
};
```

Comment: Works perfectly !! Many thanks !!! Just could you explain why just re affect my object can allow access to properties ? i don't understand why ??

Comment: When you call `Plugin.prototype.Mymethod()` `Mymethod` gets `Plugin.prototype` as this. which does not have options associated with it. 
You called init as `this.init()` so inside `init` the this is a real object which has options associated with it. 
when we call `myThis.myMethod()` it get this as `myThis` which is original object which called the `init()` and hence has the options with it. 
Did I make it clear? or make it even confusing?

Comment: just another thing @rahulmaindargi, is it correct to write `this.myMethod()` instead `myThis.myMethod()` ? if i correctly understand in that case `this` is referer to the original object ? it's not mandatory to write `var myThis = this;`

Comment: @akio No. If you looked carefully the `Mymethod` is called within `click` method which will not be called on the same object with which `init` was called. `Mymethod` belongs to object which has `init` method. but `click` method is not part of that Object.